# Повторение Visible в цикле for, при наличии во внешнем цикле while

Tags: c#, циклы

Объясните, пожалуйста, зачем в обоих циклах for в примере пишется `&& Visible`, если `Visible` уже стоит в `While`? При компиляции программы не могу увидеть разницы, что с `&& Visible` в циклах for, что без.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
    while (Visible)
    {
        for (int c = 0; c < 255 && Visible; c++)
        {
            this.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(c, 255 - c, c);
            Application.DoEvents();
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5);
        }
        for (int c = 254; c>=0 && Visible; c--)
        {
            this.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(c, 255-c, c);
            Application.DoEvents();
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: В Вашем коде `Visible` свойство формы, которое всегда `true`. Оно здесь вообще не нужно. А, `DoEvents`! Имеется в виду, что во время этого цикла может произойти событие, вызывающее выполнение другого кода, который может поменять значение `Visible` на `false`.

Comment: Это пример из книги - там пишут, что наличие Visible необходимо для остановки цикла при закрытии формы.

Comment: Эээ, уже давно не каменный век. Не применяйте ужасный `DoEvents` никогда. Не применяйте мерзкий `Thread.Sleep` никогда. Используйте божественный `async`/`await`.

Comment: @VladD: async нужен для фоновых задач не связанных с UI, а у него this.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(c, 255-c, c); Такое не прокатит;

Comment: @cpp_user: Ы? У меня всю жизнь катил, он же захватывает `SynchronizationContext`! Попробуйте сами: http://pastebin.com/k3HJzfV5

Comment: @VladD: Это шутка? Вы же не выполняете this.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(c, 255-c, c); асинхронно.

Comment: @cpp_user: Разумеется, потому что это — UI-операция. Медленные в функции ТС только sleep'ы. Вот на них у меня и await.

Comment: @VladD: Это не Sleep-ы медленные, а DoEvents быстрый. )))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Кажеться понял! В этом примере && Visible в цикле for нужно для того что бы было возможно прервать цикл for - как только Visible станет false. Иначе б возникала задержка из за того, что не было бы возможности проверить значение Visible, пока не завершиться цикл for.